# PHP action not properly determining if input fields are empty within html table

Tags: php, html

I'm using PHP to create an HTML table where each row in the table contains contains cells with an input of type "text".  At the end of the row there is a submit button that will read the data from the input fields of the table cells.

I have code written using the $_GET method to read the action of my url after the submit button is clicked but the PHP code for this action is not properly determining if the data from the input fields in the table is empty or not.

PHP Code:

```
$time_cell_row = 1;

      // <input name="userid" type="hidden" id="userid" value="<? echo $rows['userid'];

      while($tasks_row = $tasks_result->fetch_array()) {
        $time_cell_column = 1;
       echo "<form name='timesubmit" . $time_cell_row . "' action='enter_time.php?action=timesubmit" .$time_cell_row . "' method='post'>";  
       echo "<tr>
       <td>" . $tasks_row['taskname'] . "</td>
       <td><input name=taskdaycell" . $time_cell_row . $time_cell_column . " type=text></input></td>";

       $time_cell_column++;
       echo "<td><input name=taskdaycell" . $time_cell_row . $time_cell_column . " type=text></input></td>";
       $time_cell_column++;
       echo "<td><input name=taskdaycell" . $time_cell_row . $time_cell_column . " type=text></input></td>";
       $time_cell_column++;
       echo "<td><input name=taskdaycell" . $time_cell_row . $time_cell_column . " type=text></input></td>";
       $time_cell_column++;
       echo " <td><input name=taskdaycell" . $time_cell_row . $time_cell_column . " type=text></input></td>";
       $time_cell_column++;
       echo "<td><input name=taskdaycell" . $time_cell_row . $time_cell_column . " type=text></input></td>";
       $time_cell_column++;
       echo "<td><input name=taskdaycell" . $time_cell_row . $time_cell_column . " type=text></input></td>";

       echo "<td><input name=submit_time" . $time_cell_row . $time_cell_column . " type=submit></input></td>";
       echo  "</form></tr>";
       $time_cell_row++;   

      } 

if (isset($_GET['action'])) { 
    switch (strtolower($_GET['action'])) {
      case 'timesubmit1':

        if ( !isset($_POST['taskdaycell11']) || !isset($_POST['taskdaycell12']) || !isset($_POST['taskdaycell13'])
           ||  !isset($_POST['taskdaycell14']) || !isset($_POST['taskdaycell15']) || !isset($_POST['taskdaycell16'])
           || !isset($_POST['taskdaycell17'])) {

          echo "<b>Please do not leave any of the times blank</b><br>";

      }

         else {
          echo "Your times have been entered.";
         }    

        break;

   }
}
```

Right now, if I leave the table cells blank and click on the "submit" button, the output always displays "Your times have been entered" even though the input fields are blank.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your code, your switch statement is looking for 'timesubmit1' and your form is submitting the action as simply 'timesubmit'

Comment: I actually have $time_cell_row = 1 and I have the action looking for "timesubmit1".  When I click on the submit button, the url is actually displaying "action=timesubmit1"

Comment: Oh okay. I *was* misunderstanding your code.

Comment: @wavemode It's ok, I misunderstand code too sometimes.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A $_POST will always be set, whether it contains anything or not. So since your code is looking if it is set rather than looking to see if it contains anything, it is not working as you desire.

Try doing this instead.

```
if (
    empty($_POST['taskdaycell11']) ||
    empty($_POST['taskdaycell12']) ||
    empty($_POST['taskdaycell13']) || 
    empty($_POST['taskdaycell14']) ||
    empty($_POST['taskdaycell15']) ||
    empty($_POST['taskdaycell16']) ||
    empty($_POST['taskdaycell17'])
   )
{
    echo "<b>Please do not leave any of the times blank</b><br>";
}
```

**Edit:** Credit to OP for picking up the error in my code :)

Comment: I actually had it in reverse but the above code definitely helped.  Thank you so much!

Comment: That is true, i didn't pick that one up :D